# Switching from one view to another : Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have one .java file in which I have a form for user registration and I have another page on another .java file that should appear (and previous should disappear) when user clicks on next .... could anybody provide me any guidance.

Thanks a lot 
efforts appreciated

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess! you haven't tried `setVisible()` method.

Comment: @koool Not sure about your code. please edit your post and put relevant code.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 1):

Remove old content from container and add the new content. Then call `revalidate()` and `repaint()`.

Answer (score 1):

very simple by implements [Splash Screen](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) logics, you create a `JDialog` (`one .java`) and only if everything passed from `one .java` then shows something from `another .java`